# Datatable Invalid JSON response error when my JSON is valid? PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, json, datatables

My data table that is loading its body from another file with ajax is giving me the invalid JSON error, but when I check my developer tools under network responses my JSON is valid?

This is my PHP and SQL:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$output = array('data' => array());
$query = "SELECT * FROM table"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($sapconn2, $query);

$x = 1;

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $output['data'][] = array(
            'col_1' => $x,
            'ID' => $row['ID'],
            'QuoteID' => $row['QuoteID'],
            'CardCode' => $row['CardCode'],
            'SlpCode' => $row['SlpCode'],
            'SlpName' => $row['SlpName'],
            'BandA' => $row['BandA'],
            'NewPrice' => $row['NewPrice']
        );
    $x ++;
}

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

This is my JSON thats returned in the browser:

```
{
"data": [
    [1, 138, 25, "000123", "222", "test data", 222, 222],
    [2, 144, 25, "000123", "132", "test data", 465, 789],
    [3, 160, 25, "000123", "456132", "test data", 5599, 5499],
    [4, 171, 25, "000123", "789", "test data", 7897, 989],
    [5, 172, 25, "000123", "11111", "test data", 1, 11],
    [6, 182, 25, "000123", "132166", "test data", 1323, 133],
    [7, 183, 25, "000123", "135456", "test data", 1332132, 13213],
    [8, 184, 25, "000123", "1321", "test data", 5643214, 6513]
]
}
```

EDIT:

```
    var testTable = $("#testTable").DataTable({
    processing: false,
    serverSide: true,
    dataType : 'json',
    ajax: "test.php",
    columns: [
        { "data": "col_1" },
        { "data": "ID" },
        { "data": "QuoteID" },
        { "data": "CardCode" },
        { "data": "SlpCode" },
        { "data": "SlpName" },
        { "data": "BandA" },
        { "data": "NewPrice" }
    ]
    });
```

Comment: what is exactly the error?

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=testTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Comment: Please provide AJAX code, set 'dataType':'json' in it. Thanks.

Comment: AJAX added to question, thanks

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/ajax. It seems your json is not what datatable waits for.

Comment: sorry, I'm a little unsure about what you mean, could you elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what datatable waits for:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "salary": "$320,800",
            "start_date": "2011/04/25",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "5421"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The "data" element is an array of objects, instead you pass an array of array.

You need something like that:

```
{
    "data": [
        { "id": 1, "second_field": 138, "third_field": 25, "fourth_field": "000123", ... },
        { "id": 2, "second_field": 138, "third_field": 25, "fourth_field": "000123", ... },
    ]
}
```

EDITED:

```
$output['data'][] = array(
    'col_1' => $x,
    'col_2' => $row['ID'],
    'col_3' => $row['QuoteID'],
    'col_4' => $row['CardCode'],
    'col_5' => $row['SlpCode'],
    'col_6' => $row['SlpName'],
    'col_7' => $row['BandA'],
    'col_8' => $row['NewPrice']
);
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! Where would I define the fields into this format?

Comment: Okay, made them changes, my JSON data is now coming back like you said I would need, and it validates, but still, I get the same error when loading the table?

Comment: Did you add the "columns" attribute to the datatable definition?

Comment: Yes I did, I will edit my question to show you what i have done.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a request to a server-side script from DataTables with `processing` set to **`true`** then it sends [this](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters) data.

When it returns data DataTables expects the data to follow [these](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) conventions.

You can either take these into account with your server-side script (there's a good example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html).) or choose a different method for adding your data. If you perhaps set `processing` to **`false`** you might find everything just works as you expect.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, I have tried it set to false, but unfortunately, I still get the same Invalid JSON error

Comment: Hey @PHPNewbie, another issue is that when you initialize your table you are telling it to expect an array of objects whereas you're just giving it an array or arrays. The other answer gives you details of the type of data you need to return. In effect, you've got two problems at the same time: asking your server for information that it has no hope of understanding and when it does the best it can, it returns data in the wrong format. Hope taht makes sense? DataTables are built for this sort of thing but you need to clock the right way to implement them.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please give me a hand in showing me how to make this work? It would be GREATLY appriciated

Comment: Fixed it finally, i was including HTML in the document which was making it not validate. Thanks again.